# How can I pass params into children component

Tags: reactjs

I have an App route like this, I create the :topicId as a params

[image]

It renders the Quiz component, and in the Quiz component I have a Params like this (The params in the Quiz component worked perfectly, I have tested it)

[image]

And in the Quiz component I have implemented a component in, it's the QuizForm, what can I do to pass the parameter I am using at Quiz to QuizForm? Because I tried a few ways but I get undefined, maybe I'm mistaken somewhere. Thanks

[image]

Comment: wdm?  you can pass the ```quizID``` like so  ```<QuizForm quizId={quizID} />``` to ```QuizForm```. Or else you could even get ```topicId``` directly inside ```QuizForm``` too, by wrapping ```QuizForm``` like ```export default withRouter(QuizForm)``` or using hooks.

Comment: Thanks, maybe I have thought things in complicated ways and forget it right in front of my eyes, you save me!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you already have `quizID` as a variable in the context of `Quiz` component, you can pass it down to `QuizForm` as a prop:

`<QuizForm quizID={quizID} ... />`

and use it as such: `this.props.quizID`.

Comment: Thank you! It's right in front of my eyes, seem like I think it so complicated that I forgot this way. You save me.